# Php script to replace specific string in filenames from database

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I need a simple php script which needs to find files on server after reading Number column from database, copy files to another directory and then replace specific strings in saved files. For example we have files

20160107-151620_03216488727-all.mp3

20160418-105509_03225545395-all.mp3

We need to replace (03216488727, 03225545395) with the strings from database. Here is my database info:

Number                      Policy Number          Month

03216488727       123456788              2016-06

03225545395       123433339              2016-06

so after the replacement files will be

20160107-151620_123456788-all.mp3 

20160418-105509_123433339-all.mp3

Please help.

Comment: Actually I am not a php programmer, I am a system administrator and do basic shell scripting. That's why I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Comment: Actually I am not a php programmer, I am a system administrator and do basic shell scripting. That's why I need help.